# Is proving $(f: X→ Y)\land f(\varnothing)\neq\varnothing$ is a contradiction correct in the proof of this statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> **Definition 4**
>   The connective $\rightarrow$ is called the conditional and may be placed between any two statement $p$ and $q$ to form the compound statement $p→q$ (read: "if $p$, then $q$". By definition the statement $p→q$ is equivalent to the statement $\sim(p∧\sim q)$.
>
> **Definition 8**. Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. A function from $X$ to $Y$ is a triple $(f, X, Y)$, where $f$ is a relation from $X$ to $Y$ satisfying
>   (a) $\operatorname{Dom}(f) = X$.
>   (b) If $(x, y) \in f$ and $(x, z) \in f$, then $y=z$.
>   We shall adhere to the custom of writing $f: X\space \rightarrow Y$ instead of $(f, X, Y)$ and $y=f(x)$ instead of $(x,\space y) \in f$.
>
> **Definition 9** Let: $X\rightarrow Y$ be a function, and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of X and Y, respectively.
>
> (a) The image of $A$ under $f$, which we denote $f(A)$, is the set of all images $f(x)$ such that $x∈A$.
>   (b) The inverse image of B under f, which we denote $f^{-1}(B)$, is the set of all images of y in B.

In symbols, $f (A) =\{ f (x) \mid x\in A\}$,   $f^{-1}(B)=\{x \mid f (x)\in B\}$

> "Theorem 9 (a) Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$. Then $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$"
>   Source: Set Theory, You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T. Lin

The author leaves the proof of the theorem 9 to the reader. So I completed the proof by reductio ad absurdum, but I'm not sure if proving $(f: X→ Y)\land f(\varnothing)\neq \varnothing$ is a contradiction done correctly.

[My trial of proof of Theorem 9(a) by contradiction]
Let's start by negation of the statement.
$$\sim [(f: X\rightarrow Y)\rightarrow f(\varnothing)=\varnothing ]≡ \\
[(f: X\rightarrow Y)\land \sim [f(\varnothing)=\varnothing]]≡ \\  
\color{red}{[(f: X\rightarrow Y)\land} [\color{red}{f(\varnothing)\neq \varnothing} ]] $$
However, in $f(\varnothing) = \{f (x) \mid x\in \varnothing\}$, $x∈\varnothing$ is a contradiction.
Thus $[f(\varnothing)\neq \varnothing ]]≡ c\neq \varnothing ≡ c$

It's proved that $[(f: X\rightarrow Y)\Rightarrow f(\varnothing)=\varnothing ]$

Q.E.D

[Added, proof modified]
$f(Ø)≠Ø $
$⇔∃y, y∈f(Ø)$
$⇔y=f(x)∧x∈Ø$
$⇔c$   since x∈Ø is a contradiction.
Done.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof doesn't really get to the meat of the matter. The main *fallacy* you're committing is at

> However, in $f(\varnothing) = \{f (x) \mid x\in \varnothing\}$, $x∈\varnothing$ is a contradiction.

This doesn't work to conclude your proof by contradiction. It is true that *somewhere on the paper* you can now see the known false claim $x\in\varnothing$, but in order to conclude the proof-by-contradiction you have started, it is not enough for a contradicton to be *on the paper* -- it needs to be something that you have *concluded would be true* if your assumptions hold.

And in this case, what you have concluded is true is the whole formula
$$ f(\varnothing) = \{f(x)\mid x\in\varnothing\}  $$
The fact that this has "something that is always false" *inside* it doesn't make the claim *itself* "always false". As a simpler example, the formula
$$ \sim(1=0) $$
is a perfectly good truth even though it *contains* the contradiction $1=0$.

---

**In general,** your proof attempts wastes a lot of energy manipulating the assumption $f:X\to Y$. That's somewhat besides the point here and not what is done in mathematical proofs in general. Usually we just say something like

> **Theorem.** Assume $P$. Then $Q$.
>
> **Proof.** I will prove $Q$ by contradiction, so assume $\sim Q$. Then (bla bla bla bla) and we assumed $\sim Q$ and therefore (bla bla bla bla) and we assumed $P$ and therefore (bla bla bla bla) which is a contradiction. Therefore $Q$, q.e.d.

The manipulation you show is one way to justify this trope, but it's not something you would state from first principles each time you write down a proof. (That would just lead to your forest being invisible for trees). If you want to *fully formalize* your proof (which it doesn't look like you have all the tools to do yet), it *may or may not* be necessary to do something like what you're doing there, as part of the formalization. But most formal proof systems wouldn't even need that -- they have other ways of representing the reasoning above.

---

**Finally,** what you actually should have done:

Forget about the assumption $f:X\to Y$. You're not going to need it; the only reason it's in the statement of the theorem is such that it is allowed to write the notation $f(\varnothing)$ later in the statement of the theorem.

Instead we can prove *directly* that $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ by letting $y$ be arbitary and show that $\sim(y\in f(\varnothing))$ (because that's what it *means* for a set to be $\varnothing$).

By definition of $f(A)$, the subformula $y\in f(\varnothing)$ is an abbreviation for
$$ \exists x ( x\in \varnothing \land f(x)=y ) $$
and this is always false because $x\in \varnothing$ is false, which makes the existentially quantified formula false no matter what $x$ or $f$ or $y$ is.

Therefore $\sim(y\in f(\varnothing))$ and we're done.

Comment: What does $y$ stand for in $ \exists y ( y\in \varnothing \land f(y)=x ) $?

Comment: @buzzee - Def 9(a) The image of $A$ under $f$, which we denote $f(A)$, is the set of all images $f(y)$ such that $y∈A$ [ $f(A)= \{ f(y) \mid y∈A \}$ ], i.e. $x \in f(A)$ **iff** $f(y)=x$, for some $x \in A$.

Comment: Then x and y in your answer are reversed.

The image of $Ø$ under f in symbols is $f(Ø)$={$f(x)|x∈Ø$}

So 
$f(Ø)≠Ø $  
$⇔∃y, y∈f(Ø)$   
$⇔∃y, y=f(x)∧x∈Ø$   
$⇔c$   since x∈Ø is a contradiction.  
Done. 

Q.E.D.

Comment: @buzzee: You're right, it would be more instructive to swap the variable letters; so done.